# iOS app crashs on startup error

Tags: xamarin

I noticed that my app installed on iPhone from Appstore crashed immediatly after startup. I removed it from the phone and installed it again, everything worked.

Now I have to modify that app, I developed it with visual studio and xamarin.
When I try to debug the app on a device I can only see the splash image, then the app crash

I tried to put breakpoints on visual studio, in the AppDelegate.cs file too, but none of them are hitted.

the crash log found on the mac is:

> Incident Identifier: D467E779-D524-4F17-A125-4024E1C088D7
>   CrashReporter Key:   14d9c0d9f9fd92fe140f6f76ff2facb91db70c6e
>   Hardware Model:      iPhone5,2
>  Process:             tabbed
>   [974]
>  Path:
>   /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/E5A36250-868F-4330-A950-1E9A6FE13294/tabbed.app/tabbed
>   Identifier:          it.fi.comune.firenzeup
>  Version:
>   1.1.38 (1.1.38)
>  Code Type:           ARM (Native)
>  Parent Process:      launchd [1]
>   
>   
>  Date/Time:
>   2016-09-15 14:44:56.56 +0200
>  Launch Time:         2016-09-15
>   14:44:55.55 +0200
>  OS Version:          iOS 9.3.4 (13G35)
>   Report Version:      105
>   
>   
>  Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH
>   (SIGABRT)
>  Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000,
>   0x0000000000000000
>  Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
>   Triggered by Thread:  0
>   
>   
>  Filtered syslog:
>  None
>   found
>   
>   
>  Last Exception Backtrace:
>  (0x21639b06
>   0x20df6dfa 0xa9b56 0xdaff8 0x20df7ab6 0x20dfd998 0x20dfd89e 0x20e03d16
>   0x7ed9ce 0x7ee5de 0x1e92ac 0x7ee74c 0x211f486e)
>   
>   
>  Thread
>   0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
>  Thread 0
>   Crashed:
>  0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x212c7c5c 0x212b3000
>   + 85084
>  1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x2136db46 0x2136a000 + 15174
>  2   libsystem_c.dylib             0x2125c0c4 0x21211000 +
>   307396
>  3   libc++abi.dylib               0x20dd27dc 0x20dd2000 +
>   2012
>  4   libc++abi.dylib               0x20deb6a0 0x20dd2000 +
>   104096
>  5   libobjc.A.dylib               0x20df7098 0x20df0000 +
>   28824
>  6   libc++abi.dylib               0x20de8e16 0x20dd2000 +
>   93718
>  7   libc++abi.dylib               0x20de85f4 0x20dd2000 +
>   91636
>  8   libobjc.A.dylib               0x20df6ed2 0x20df0000 +
>   28370
>  9   tabbed                         0x000a9b5a 0x8000 +
>   662362
>  10  tabbed                         0x000daffc 0x8000 +
>   864252
>  11  libobjc.A.dylib               0x20df7aba 0x20df0000 +
>   31418
>  12  libobjc.A.dylib               0x20dfd99c 0x20df0000 +
>   55708
>  13  libobjc.A.dylib               0x20dfd8a2 0x20df0000 +
>   55458
>  14  libobjc.A.dylib               0x20e03d1a 0x20df0000 +
>   81178
>  15  tabbed                         0x007ed9d2 0x8000 +
>   8280530
>  16  tabbed                         0x007ee5e2 0x8000 +
>   8283618
>  17  tabbed                         0x001e92b0 0x8000 +
>   1970864
>  18  tabbed                         0x007ee750 0x8000 +
>   8283984
>  19  libdyld.dylib                 0x211f4872 0x211f2000 +
>   10354
>   
>   
>  Thread 1:
>  0   libsystem_kernel.dylib
>   0x212c8864 0x212b3000 + 88164
>  1   libsystem_pthread.dylib
>   0x2136ae18 0x2136a000 + 3608
>  2   libsystem_pthread.dylib
>   0x2136a9fc 0x2136a000 + 2556
>   
>   
>  Thread 2 name:  Dispatch
>   queue: com.apple.libdispatch-manager
>  Thread 2:
>  0
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x212c92f8 0x212b3000 + 90872
>  1
>   libdispatch.dylib             0x211db836 0x211c7000 + 84022
>  2
>   libdispatch.dylib             0x211cd916 0x211c7000 + 26902
>   
>  
>   
>  Thread 3:
>  0   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x212c8864
>   0x212b3000 + 88164
>  1   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x2136ae18
>   0x2136a000 + 3608
>  2   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x2136a9fc
>   0x2136a000 + 2556
>   
>   
>  Thread 4:
>  0
>   libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x212c8864 0x212b3000 + 88164
>  1
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x2136ae18 0x2136a000 + 3608
>  2
>   libsystem_pthread.dylib       0x2136a9fc 0x2136a000 + 2556
>   
>  
>   
>  Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
>       r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x00000000
>       r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x382b9000      r6: 0x37516304      r7: 0x014e68e8
>       r8: 0x17d61670    r9: 0x20dec8fc     r10: 0x2665fd10     r11: 0x17d61694
>       ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x014e68dc      lr: 0x2136db47      pc: 0x212c7c5c
>    cpsr: 0x00000010
>   
>   
>  Binary Images:
>   0x8000 - 0x90bfff tabbed armv7  
>   /var/containers/Bundle/Application/E5A36250-868F-4330-A950-1E9A6FE13294/tabbed.app/tabbed
>   0x1feba000 - 0x1fee1fff dyld armv7s 
>   <023542032680372f8d383c4c2b42a8a3> /usr/lib/dyld
>  0x20d84000 -
>   0x20d85fff libSystem.B.dylib armv7s 
>   <97146dbaa54a32f5bb5371bbdb465368> /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib
>   0x20d86000 - 0x20dd1fff libc++.1.dylib armv7s 
>   <82abc45878c53dfd8e59d088ead88952> /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib
>   0x20dd2000 - 0x20decfff libc++abi.dylib armv7s 
>    /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
>   0x20df0000 - 0x2115afff libobjc.A.dylib armv7s 
>    /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
>   0x2115b000 - 0x2115ffff libcache.dylib armv7s 
>   <2b39436eaf1c3aa384dc88d909bb82ea> /usr/lib/system/libcache.dylib
>   0x21160000 - 0x21169fff libcommonCrypto.dylib armv7s 
>   <39d4afd1f66738cd839cb5653496c3ee>
>   /usr/lib/system/libcommonCrypto.dylib
>  0x2116a000 - 0x2116efff
>   libcompiler_rt.dylib armv7s  <1b2198e6340836198081bc7f5f1877fa>
>   /usr/lib/system/libcompiler_rt.dylib
>  0x2116f000 - 0x21175fff
>   libcopyfile.dylib armv7s  <71718805ccf33657b701b893581eac47>
>   /usr/lib/system/libcopyfile.dylib
>  0x21176000 - 0x211c6fff
>   libcorecrypto.dylib armv7s  <336af202343e3aeb9dfca3c78bc2da15>
>   /usr/lib/system/libcorecrypto.dylib
>  0x211c7000 - 0x211f1fff
>   libdispatch.dylib armv7s  <6a8fa64935873703b59839b66ee598fc>
>   /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib
>  0x211f2000 - 0x211f4fff
>   libdyld.dylib armv7s  <7da9a8ef840834c3ba50a1adaffecad5>
>   /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib

Can anyone help me?
Thanks

Comment: Maybe it will be useful http://stackoverflow.com/a/39560929/3718570

Comment: SOLVED - it was a problem with the info.plist, the controller specified in <key>NSMainNibFile</key> was really never called, the app delegate call another view. I removed the key form the plist file and everything is ok now. Don't know why it didn't cause problem before.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered similar problems with a Xamarin app I created.
The problem in my case had to do with the assembly Linker.

Initial the linker was set to **'Don't link'**. This is not optimal because the size of the app will be huge.
So I changed the setting to '**Link SDK assemblies only**'. The app size was reduced dramatically but the linker was a bit rigorous.

I had to tell the linker to skip some assemblies. By trial and error I came to the following assemblies that needed to be included:

- --linkskip System.Runtime
- --linkskip System.IO.FileNotFoundException
- --linkskip System.Threading
- --linkskip System.Threading.Tasks
- --linkskip System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations

This don't mean that these assemblies are also affecting you, but might give you a clue in what direction you can find your solution.

In Visual Studio you can add the arguments as 'Additional mtouch arguments'
[Visual Studio image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbXTG.png)